# When automount ntfs partition, all file were marked "Allow executing file as program"

Tags: ntfs, automount, fstab, text, executable

I edited /etc/fstab to automount NTFS partition, then all file were marked "Allow executing file as program". How can I fix it?

EDIT:
When I double click any text file, it didn't show immediately, a dialog was displayed, and I must choose Display option to view it in gedit.

Comment: Is there something to "fix"?  NTFS has no conception of execute bit; nevertheless it is entirely possible for executable files (scripts, Unix executables, even Windows EXEs if you have Wine configured properly) to be present.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a problem...

Comment: text file is example. When I double-click to a text file, a dialog is displayed, and I can choose "Run", "Display".... I saw  it's propertity "Allow executing file as program" was checked.

Comment: But what's the problem with this behavior?

Comment: @SirCharlo: If I don't automount NTFS partition, I can open text file immediately (1 step). But now, I must double click, and then I must choose Display option (2 steps).

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Add `noexec` to the options for that partition in your fstab.

Comment: @SirCarlo I think Adding more details will be helpful for new user. Can you edit it to include more details.